# Не адаптивная верстка

Tags: bootstrap, вёрстка

Решил для себя полностью верстать все проекты под Bootstrap 3, но как я понял он для адаптивного дизайна.
А можно на нем сделать простой сайт не адаптивный, чтоб при уменьшении экрана появлялась горизонтальная полоса прокрутки и не происходило перестраивания элементов?

Answer (score 2):

Почитайте в официальной документации раздел [Disabling responsiveness](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive), там описано, как отключить адаптивность в 3-ем бутсрапе.

Answer (score 2):

В примерах есть не адаптивный макет - [Non-responsive Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/)